# when mouseover on image show div with linkbutton

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the below code for showing linkbutton in div and when it clicks it should go to that link.
This is not working for me correctly.I tried the below code.Just check and tell where I am wrong.
It is working good in this site when a user answer to any question and we hover on that user image we got his/her profile and there is also a link to see their profile. Exactly this concept is same what I am searching, So please help.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
          <head>

              <title></title>
                  <style>
                    div.out { width:40%; height:120px; margin:0 15px;
                     background-color:#D6EDFC; float:left; }
                      div.in { width:60%; height:60%;
                 background-color:#FFCC00; margin:10px auto; }
                 p { line-height:1em; margin:0; padding:0; }

                    </style>
                             <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
                      </head>
               <body>
                 <form id="form1" runat="server">

                 <img src="Images/orderedList2.png" id="actionImage" />
                  <div class="out overout">
                  <span>move your mouse</span>
                  <div class="in">
               <p>The function bigImg() is triggered when the user moves the mouse pointer over the image.</p>
          <a href="www.google.com" id="A1" class="target">www.google.com</a>
                     </div>
                    </div>
               <div class="out enterleave">
                  <span>move your mouse</span>
                      <div class="in" >
                               <p>The function bigImg() is triggered when the user moves the                                                      mouse pointer over the image.</p>
                     <a href="www.google.com" id="url" class="target">www.google.com</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
           <script type="text/javascript">

              $('#actionImage').mouseover(function (e) {
              $("div.enterleave").show();
              $('#actionImage').mouseout(function () {
              $("div.enterleave").hide();

            });
           });

          $("div.enterleave").mouseenter(function () {
          $(this).show();
          }).mouseleave(function () {
             $(this).hide();
             });

           </script>


                </form>
                </body>
                   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Address is wrong you should put the protocol of the request to the address and not simply the address. So you need to change the href parameter in your  tag like so:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="A1" class="target">www.google.com</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="url" class="target">www.google.com</a>
```

To know more about protocols i advise the following

http://computernetworkingnotes.com/network-technologies/protocol-tcp-ip-udp-ftp-tftp-smtp.html

Commons Protocols

Port Number - Service

80 -  HTTP

21 - FTP
110 - POP3

25 - SMTP

23 - Telnet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the JS you have going but a basic error in your code is that your links need to have "http://"

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="url" class="target">www.google.com</a>
```

replace with

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="url" class="target">www.google.com</a>
```

because external link should be start with http or Https